# Get header when enumerate an array

Tags: swift, macos

i try to get header informations about remote files which url are located in an array.
My function to get header works perfectly when called alone but doesn't when inside array enumerate.
Here my functions:

```
    func getHeaderInformations (myUrl: URL, completion: @escaping (_ content: String?) -> ()) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil, let reponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, let contentType = reponse.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"],let contentLength = reponse.allHeaderFields["Content-Length"]

            else{
                completion(nil)
                return
        }
        let content = String(describing: contentType) + "/" + String(describing: contentLength)

        completion(content)
    }
    task.resume()
}

    // download picture
func downloadPic (){
    let minimumSize=UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Minimum_size") as! Int64
    var imgExtension:String=""
    var type:String=""
    var size:Int64=0

    for (_,item) in LiensImgArrayURL.enumerated() {
        getHeaderInformations(myUrl: item, completion: { content in
           let myInfoArray = content?.components(separatedBy: "/")
            type=(myInfoArray?[0])!
            imgExtension=(myInfoArray?[1])!
            size=Int64((myInfoArray?[2])!)!
        })
        if (type=="image" && size>=minimumSize) {
            SaveFileToDirectory(myRemoteUrl: item, myExtension: imgExtension)
        }
        }
}
```

How can i write well this code for "getHeaderInformations" works and return good values inside the func "downLoadPic"?

Thanks for your answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `getHeaderInformations` works asynchronously put the code to save the file **in** the closure.

If you don't need the index in the `for` loop you don't need `enumerated()` either.

I tweaked the code bit to get rid of ugly question and exclamation marks and parentheses.

```
for item in LiensImgArrayURL {
    getHeaderInformations(myUrl: item, completion: { content in
       if let myInfoArray = content?.components(separatedBy: "/") {
            type = myInfoArray[0]
            imgExtension = myInfoArray[1]
            size = Int64(myInfoArray[2])!
            if type == "image" && size >= minimumSize {
                SaveFileToDirectory(myRemoteUrl: item, myExtension: imgExtension)
            }
       }
    })
}
```